# Possible bug in JToggleButton API?

Tags: java, swing, border-layout, jtogglebutton

I got an example for JToggleButton from [java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/newJToggleButtonStringtext.htm). In the code, I see that a toggle button does not display text properly if the text is "West". West is shown as We.. . Everything else is okay. But there is no problem when text = "west", ie w small. Is this a bug?

[image]

Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public class MainClass {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
 JFrame f = new JFrame("JToggleButton Sample");
 f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 f.add(new JToggleButton("North"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
 f.add(new JToggleButton("East"), BorderLayout.EAST);
 f.add(new JToggleButton("West"), BorderLayout.WEST);
 f.add(new JToggleButton("Center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
 f.add(new JToggleButton("South"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 f.setSize(300, 200);
 f.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: Try using f.pack(); instead of f.setSize(...)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Smaller window, but error still persists. It happens when text = West.

Comment: So you changed all the buttons text to "West" then?

Comment: @MadProgrammer - All changed to west. Now left and right button are messed up. Top, center, bottom are ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MetalLookAndFeel - getPreferredSize isn't calculated correctly

[image]

SystemLookAndFeel

[image]

Nimbus

[image]

Substance

[image]

from code (same issue with JFrame, JPanel as container by using BorderLayout)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            "org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceOfficeBlue2007LookAndFeel");
                    //UIManager.getDefaults();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });

       /*try {
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo laf : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(laf.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf.getClassName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("JToggleButton Sample");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                panel.add(new JToggleButton("North"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                panel.add(new JToggleButton("East"), BorderLayout.EAST);
                panel.add(new JToggleButton("West"), BorderLayout.WEST);
                panel.add(new JToggleButton("Center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                panel.add(new JToggleButton("South"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                f.add(panel);
                f.pack();
                //f.setSize(300, 200);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: same from Win8 as I see OPs screenshot

Comment: Looks like its a bug in the MetalLookAndFeel. But its probably too small an issue for oracle. Dont use any word which begins with w in your code.

Comment: @SuperStar then report it,  [you'll be real SuperStar with own bug in Official BugParade](http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/),

Comment: mKorbel - You guys are the REAL superstar. I am only a small caffeine addict :)

Comment: The form in the link is complicated. It can be simplified. The form is also the main "bug". How do I put a request to fix that ? May be thats why some bugs don't get reported.

Comment: agreed all steps there are awfull :-), never hand up, never give up

Comment: Sent a bug report. Lets see how that goes.

Comment: probably with zero priority, if yes then long time you'll see that here, upto Java8 ...

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work just fine for me...

[image][image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLayout23 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout23();
    }

    public TestLayout23() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame f = new JFrame("JToggleButton Sample");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(new JToggleButton("North"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                f.add(new JToggleButton("East"), BorderLayout.EAST);
                f.add(new JToggleButton("West"), BorderLayout.WEST);
                f.add(new JToggleButton("Center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                f.add(new JToggleButton("South"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: That looks like Mac OS UI. I am on win-DODO-ws. Try removing that set look and feel code.

Comment: @mKorbel - Not sure if I understand you. You mean - Not an issue. It happens only with MetalLookAndFeel on Win7 Java6/7. Right ?

Comment: see my quick test, its regular bug,

Comment: @SuperStar Don't be fictitious. You did not mention any where in you answer OS or Look and Feel

Comment: @MadProgrammer - sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: @SuperStar Firstly, I've been up since 330am taking care of a baby who won't sleep unless someone is holding her, so I'm a little tetchy, but I find this comment - *I am on win-DODO-ws* slight offensive (the comment it self wasn't really, I just come across as such) (and I'm sure you didn't mean to be), but you didn't mention anything about what platform or look and feel you were testing. As it turns out, you did find a bug - Well done ;)